# Order by Names in SQL in Priority

Tags: mysql

I have a list of options in the drop down. Where i am  using 'ORDER BY NAMES' in SQL. But if i search "man" keyword the list it displaying is shown in below image. here my question is i am getting this list because of CASE sensitive?

After the first two options it is displaying correctly. How can i display the 3,4 options first as they have alphabetical order.

I have also tried ORDER BY LOWER(NAMES) still getting same solutions.

[image: ss]

Answer (score 0):

I don't like linking off site so I will repeat the answer here:

> If you want to explicity specify the order of which 'order by' comes back in, like if you had a priority field that had the values "Low" "High" or "Medium" .. do this:

```
select * from tablename 
order by priority='High' DESC, 
priority='Medium' DESC, priority='Low" DESC;
```

credit for answer: [MySQL dev](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html) Billy Kimble